# MongoDB Update / Upsert Question - Schema Related

Tags: schema, mongodb, pymongo, document-oriented-db

I have an problem representing data in MongoDB.  I was using this schema design, where a combination of date and word is unique.

```
{'date':2-1-2011,
'word':word1'
users = [user1, user2, user3, user4]}

{'date':1-1-2011,
'word':word2'
users = [user1, user2]}
```

There are a fixed number of dates, approximately 200; potentially 100k+ words for each date; and 100k+ users.

I inserted records with an algorithm like so:

```
while records exist:
    message, user, date = pop a record off a list
    words = set(tokenise(message))

    for word in words:
        collection1.insert({'date':date, 'word':word}, {'user':user})
        collection2.insert('something similar')
        collection3.insert('something similar again')
        collection4.insert('something similar again')
```

However, this schema resulted in extremely large collections and terrible performance was terrible.  I am inserting different information into each of the four collections, so it is an extremely large number of operations on the database.

I'm considering representing the data in a format like so, where the words and users arrays are sets.

```
{'date':'26-6-2011',
 'words': [
'word1': ['user1', 'user2'],
'word2': ['user1']
'word1': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']]}
```

The idea behind this was to cut down on the number of database operations.  So that for each loop of the algorithm, I perform just one update for each collection.  However, I am unsure how to perform an update / upsert on this because with each loop of the algorithm, I may need to insert a new word, user, or both.

Could anyone recommend either a way to update this document, or could anyone suggest an alternative schema?

Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity: in what way was your performance terrible? write performance or queries?

Comment: @deadsven, write and update performance.  Queries are fast, but writes and update are performing poorly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upsert is well suited for dynamically extending documents. Unfortunately I only found it working properly if you have an atomic modifier operation in your update object. like the $addToSet here (mongo shell code):

db.words is empty. add first document for a given date with an upsert.

```
var query = { 'date' : 'date1' }                        
var update = { $addToSet: { 'words.word1' :  'user1' } }
db.words.update(query,update,true,false)
```

check object.

```
db.words.find();                                        
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e3bd4eccf7604a2180c4905"), "date" : "date1", "words" : { "word1" : [ "user1" ] } }
```

now add some more users to first word and another word in one update.

```
var update = { $addToSet: { 'words.word1' : { $each : ['user2', 'user4', 'user5'] }, 'words.word2': 'user3' } }
db.words.update(query,update,true,false)
```

again, check object.

```
db.words.find()                                                                                                
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e3bd7e9cf7604a2180c4907"), "date" : "date1", "words" : { "word1" : [ "user1", "user2", "user4", "user5" ], "word2" : [ "user3" ] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MongoDB to insert 105mil records with ~10 attributes each.  Instead of updating this dataset with changes, I just delete and re insert everything.  I found this method to be faster than individually touching each row to see if it was one that I needed to update.  You will have better insert speeds if you create JSON formatted text files and use MongoDB's mongoimport tool.

1. format your data into JSON txt files (one file per collection)
2. mongoimport each file and specify the collection you want it inserted into